# eclipselink moxy xpath - selecting all child elements of the current node or all elements in a document with a particular name

Tags: xpath, eclipselink, moxy

i have this xpath defined for moxy in a jaxb class

@XmlPath("child::*/REG")
public List entries;

but it won't unmarshal the xml document correctly.  the List variable called entries is empty.

i've also tried

@XmlPath("*/REG")
public List entries;

i've also tried

@XmlPath("//REG")
public List entries;

without joy

but if i do

@XmlPath("BANKGIRO/REG")
public List entries;

it's fine and the list is populated.

I haven't looked through the source yet but I'm guessing this type of xpath is not supported yet.  I checked all my xpath in an xpath verifier for sanity and all the xpath above is fine (all the xpath is valid for the context node i'm positioned at).

Comment: It seems that the tool you are using isn't a compliant XPath processor. Have you tried `*/REG` ?

Comment: one of the first things i tried actually.  this also proved to be fruitless

Comment: i've added */REG to the list above for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)** does currently not support an XPath like: `@XmlPath("child::*/REG")`.  Our focus has been on supporting XPath statements that provide enough information for marshalling as well as unmarshalling.  For example it is clear what `@XmlPath("child::*/REG")` means on a read, but is ambiguous in terms when writing that object back to XML or JSON.  If you are interested in this kind of support please enter an enhancement request:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink

MOXy does support XPath like:

- @XmlPath(".") // Map to self node, useful when mapping two objects to same element
- @XmlPath("@foo") // Map to attribute
- @XmlPath("foo") // Map to element
- @XmlPath("foo[2]") // Map to 2nd occurence of
- @XmlPath("foo[@bar='Hello World']") // Map to foo element with bar attribute with value "Hello World"
- @XmlPath("ns1:foo/ns2:@bar") // Map to namespace qualified nodes

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Comment: I thought it would be because mapping back to xml would be ambiguous but a simple XmlElement(name="blah") (use xpath when unmarshalling, and XmlElement when marshalling) would seem to me to be a way out.  however, I am aware that the ramifications of my solution may mean that it is not as easy as it seems.  otherwise great product.  i shall raise the request

Comment: I'm happy to hear you're enjoying MOXy.  This is definitely an interesting use case.  I would appreciate any thoughts you have in terms of what the metadata might look like.

Comment: i've raised the change request already, at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373400.  hope i can help.  just so others are aware the | operator also isn't supported.